# Updating all cells on a table view without making the operation too "heavy" for memory

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

I have a `table view` with `cells`, and they can show a checkmark when left swipe action is implemented (the checkmark is just a `UIView`, which property `isHidden` gets set to true).

I also have a `UIButton` on another `view controller`, and when a user taps it, all checkmarks should be removed. I implement this by using a protocol and a `bool` computed property on the delegate. The property is called from the protocol.

Here is the method implementation:

```
extension ItemsTableViewController: UncheckAllCheckedItemsDelegate {
func uncheckAllCheckedItemsButtonDidTapped() {
    if checkedItems.count > 0 {
        checkedItems.removeAll()
        shouldShowCheckmarks = false
    }
}

}
```

From the property observer of the property (`didSet`), I call `reloadData()` on a `table view`.

Here how it looks like:

```
var shouldShowCheckmarks: Bool = false {
    didSet {

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I use this property in `table view`'s data source method `tableView(_:, cellForRawAt:)` like this:

```
 cell.checkMarkView.isHidden = !shouldShowCheckmarks
```

It works fine, and all cells get updated (even those, that are not currently visible).

Now, I'm not sure whether it is the best way to update all `cells` in terms of memory usage. If you know a better way to do this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Show. Your. Code. You ask us whether what you're doing is okay, but you don't _show_ us what you're doing. Are we supposed to just _guess_?

Comment: @matt, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to update the check mark for the visible cells.  Fortunately, there is a property of `UITableView` to help you called `visibleCells`.

Instead of calling reload data:

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    // update the check mark for this cell
    cell.checkMarkView.isHidden = !shouldShowCheckmarks
}
```

As long as you have updated your model data, your non-visible cells will do the right thing the next time they are loaded.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a better solution. Thank you for your help